# Decrypt parameter store secrets conditionally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a policy to allow users to view all the parameter store values unless it is encrypted by the `dev` kms key. The following is the policy that i've written.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyDecryptForDevKey",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "kms:RequestAlias": "dev"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowDecryptIfNotDevKey",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "kms:RequestAlias": "dev"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "GetSSMParameters",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssm:GetParameter",
            "ssm:GetParameters",
            "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

but when i'm trying to create it in the UI, these are the following permissions it shows that are defined in the policy.

```
| Explicit deny (1 of 402 services) |
|------------------------------------|
| Service      | Access level | Resource       | Request condition        |
|--------------|--------------|----------------|---------------------------|
| KMS          | Limited: Write | All resources | kms:RequestAlias = dev |

| Allow (1 of 402 services)         |
|-----------------------------------|
| Service          | Access level | Resource       | Request condition |
|------------------|--------------|----------------|-------------------|
| KMS  | Limited: Write | All resources | kms:RequestAlias !== dev             |
| Systems Manager  | Limited: Read | All resources | None              |
```

This is how i am testing it :

1. Create a parameter with type `SecureString` and encrypt it with key `dev`
2. Create another parameter with type `SecureString` and encrypt it with key that is not `dev`.
3. Create a Role. `testing-role` with Trusted entity type as AWS account.
4. Create an IAM policy with the above permissions and attach to the role.
5. Switch role from the UI inputting the name of the role i.e. `testing-role` that i created as well as the AWS account ID.
6. After switching to the role, go to the parameters that were created and try to view the value by toggling `Show decrypted value`

But somehow I'm still able to decrypt any secrets encrypted by `dev` key. Thank you.

Comment: Suspect having both the allow and deny won't help debugging - only the allow should be necessary unless there are other parts to the policy not reflected here? Is the alias definitely named `alias/dev`?

Comment: Possibly a request / resource alias thing? From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/alias-authorization.html) `The permission is effective only when the request uses an alias that includes alpha to identify the KMS key` How are you testing it?

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 thank you for the message. yeah the alias was wrong and i'm updating it above as well as adding how i'm testing it.

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 even after updating the alias, the behavior remains the same.

Comment: I think as referenced in the docs you're not necessarily requesting by alias - I'd try implementing the ResourceAliases condition and try and avoid negation in the policy where possible - it's not very failsafe

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 thank you so much for the assistance for this. I am adding the policy below that worked but please add your answer officially and I'll accept it since you deserve complete credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [distinction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/alias-authorization.html) between allowing or denying requests to `kms:Decrypt` based on whether the request is made by alias or by id or ARN. Setting a condition on the IAM policy relating to RequestAlias only affects those requests by alias.

> However, a request that used a key ID, a key ARN, or a different alias
> would not fulfill the condition, even if these values identified the
> same KMS key.

[Using the resource alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/alias-authorization.html#alias-auth-request-alias) appears to fit the requirement here.
And [allow for multiple aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/conditions-kms.html#conditions-kms-resource-aliases) by using the set operator conditions

There is an additional factor here of allowing unconditionally and then denying particular elements conditionally rather than the safer approach of allowing only what is intended.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowDecrypt",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
                    "kms:ResourceAliases": "alias/dev*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "GetSSMParameters",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tested in the [Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/) as much as reasonably possible without access to the precise keys you're trying to protect to check aliases.

Comment: just small addition. `ForAnyValue:StringNotLike`

Comment: Had failed to work out why `ForAnyValue` was needed when I wrote the answer but I was testing against a key with a single alias.

Answer (score 0):

This is the policy that worked.

```
 {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "DenyDecryptIfDevKey",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                        "kms:ResourceAliases": "alias/dev*"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "AllowDecrypt",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Sid": "GetSSMParameters",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ssm:GetParameter",
                    "ssm:GetParameters",
                    "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
```